# Minecraft 1.16.2 on Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: raspbian, pi-4, java, minecraft, games

As of this writing, I have been attempting for some time now to get Minecraft 1.16.2 working on my Raspberry pi 4. I have been using the instructions on this guide which helped me set up Minecraft 1.16.1 in the past:

https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=1694049

I have so far attempted to alter runMC1_16_1_OptifineG2pre.sh to make it 1.16.2 friendly. I downloaded the latest Optifine preview release for 1.16.2 and installed it into the versions folder. Then I edited these lines in the runMC file to point to it:

```
MINECRAFT_NATIVE_PATH=$HOME/$LWJGLARM/
OPTIFINE_NUM=1.16.1
OPTIFINE_VER=HD_U_G2_pre2
```

to

```
MINECRAFT_NATIVE_PATH=$HOME/$LWJGLARM/
OPTIFINE_NUM=1.16.2
OPTIFINE_VER=HD_U_G3_pre1
```

In theory, this should have worked, but it didn't and here I am. This is the error it has been giving me so far:

```
[18:30:08] [main/INFO]: Launching wrapped minecraft {net.minecraft.client.main.Main}
[18:30:10] [main/INFO]: [OptiFine] (Reflector) Field not found: World.tileEntitiesToBeRemoved
[18:30:10] [main/INFO]: [OptiFine] (Reflector) Class not present: net.minecraftforge.eventbus.api.Event$Result
[18:30:10] [main/INFO]: [OptiFine] (Reflector) Method not present: net.minecraftforge.common.extensions.IForgeBlockState.hasTileEntity
[18:30:10] [main/INFO]: [OptiFine] (Reflector) Class not present: net.minecraftforge.common.extensions.IForgeEntity
[18:30:10] [main/INFO]: [OptiFine] (Reflector) Class not present: net.minecraftforge.fml.CrashReportExtender
[18:30:11] [main/ERROR]: Unable to launch
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_251]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_251]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_251]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_251]
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.launch(Launch.java:159) [launchwrapper-of-2.1.jar:2.1]
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.main(Launch.java:30) [launchwrapper-of-2.1.jar:2.1]
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.mojang.serialization.MapCodec.setPartial(Ljava/util/function/Supplier;)Lcom/mojang/serialization/MapCodec;
    at cef.a(SourceFile:75) ~[cef.class:?]
    at cef.<init>(SourceFile:41) ~[cef.class:?]
    at cef$a.a(SourceFile:154) ~[cef$a.class:?]
    at bul.<init>(SourceFile:178) ~[bul.class:?]
    at bzy.<init>(SourceFile:16) ~[bzy.class:?]
    at cae.<init>(SourceFile:17) ~[cae.class:?]
    at bwy.<init>(SourceFile:16) ~[bwy.class:?]
    at bum.<clinit>(SourceFile:107) ~[bum.class:?]
    at ctq.<clinit>(SourceFile:13) ~[ctq.class:?]
    at kp.<clinit>(SourceFile:11) ~[kp.class:?]
    at hk.g(SourceFile:44) ~[hk.class:?]
    at hk.a(SourceFile:75) ~[hk.class:?]
    at java.util.LinkedHashMap.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:684) ~[?:1.8.0_251]
    at hk.<clinit>(SourceFile:74) ~[hk.class:?]
    at gm.<clinit>(SourceFile:237) ~[gm.class:?]
    at vm.a(SourceFile:42) ~[vm.class:?]
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(SourceFile:137) ~[Main.class:?]
    ... 6 more
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Use the newer tutorial that uses the official old launcher:

https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=78&t=284448

At least until Microsoft blocks Mojang accounts.

Answer (score 0):

Optifine wont work if theres no 1.16.2 Minecraft. **You need to update too...**

Answer (score 0):

Two other libraries were updated from 1.16.**1** to 1.16.**2**

`~/.minecraft/libraries/optifine/launchwrapper-of/` moved from 2.**1** to 2.**2**

`~/.minecraft/libraries/com/mojang/datafixerupper/` moved from **3.0.25** to **4.0.26**

You need to edit your runMC1_16_2_{opti version}.sh to reflect this, the line to edit starts `CP=$HOME/` and is about 3k chars long.

Mine runs after making these edits.