# Minecraft 1.16.4 on Raspberry Pi 4 fais to launch with errors

Tags: pi-4, java, minecraft

I'm getting an error trying to launch 1.16.4. Here are the steps I've done so far:

- Got Minecraft 1.16.1 with Optifine working on my RPI4 following the steps on the
  [How to setup Minecraft 1.16.1 on Pi4](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=1694049) raspberrypi.org forum post
- Got Minecraft 1.16.2 (and similarly 1.16.3) with Optifine to launch successfully by following this stackexchange answer: [Minecraft 1.16.2 on Raspberry Pi 4](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/117757/126834)
- run the vanilla minecraft launcher.jar and started the "download and run" step for 1.16.4 which successfully downloaded the jar and resources for minecraft 1.16.4 and (as expected) failed to launch it
- ran the OptiFine_1.16.4_HD_U_G5.jar installer which completed successfully
- created a runMC1.16.4_Optifine_HD_U_G5.sh launcher script, working from my working 1.16.2 / 1.16.3 scripts and updating these lines: OPTIFINE_NUM=1.16.4 and OPTIFINE_VER=HD_U_G5

However when running this script I get an error launching minecraft. The callstack seems to be related to launchwrapper-of-2.2 -- however this is the same version used by the 1.16.2 and 1.16.3 versions of Optifine, and I was able to run those successfully. Anyone familiar with what could be going on here and how to fix it?

Here's the relevant log output:

> [12:15:58] [main/ERROR]: Unable to launch
> java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_251]
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_251]
> at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_251]
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_251]
> at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.launch(Launch.java:159) [**launchwrapper-of-2.2.jar**:2.2]
> at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.main(Launch.java:30) [**launchwrapper-of-2.2.jar**:2.2]
> Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mojang/authlib/minecraft/SocialInteractionsService
> at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_251]
> at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2583) ~[?:1.8.0_251]
> at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1916) ~[?:1.8.0_251]
> at net.optifine.reflect.FieldLocatorTypes.(FieldLocatorTypes.java:25) ~[FieldLocatorTypes.class:?]
> at net.optifine.reflect.Reflector.(Reflector.java:489) ~[Reflector.class:?]
> at l.i(CrashReport.java:101) ~[l.class:?]
> at l.(CrashReport.java:54) ~[l.class:?]
> at l.h(CrashReport.java:425) ~[l.class:?]
> at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(SourceFile:135) ~[Main.class:?]
> ... 6 more
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mojang.authlib.minecraft.SocialInteractionsService
> at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.LaunchClassLoader.findClass(LaunchClassLoader.java:186) ~[**launchwrapper-of-2.2.jar**:2.2]
> at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418) ~[?:1.8.0_251]
> at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351) ~[?:1.8.0_251]
> at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_251]
> at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2583) ~[?:1.8.0_251]
> at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1916) ~[?:1.8.0_251]
> at net.optifine.reflect.FieldLocatorTypes.(FieldLocatorTypes.java:25) ~[FieldLocatorTypes.class:?]
> at net.optifine.reflect.Reflector.(Reflector.java:489) ~[Reflector.class:?]
> at l.i(CrashReport.java:101) ~[l.class:?]
> at l.(CrashReport.java:54) ~[l.class:?]
> at l.h(CrashReport.java:425) ~[l.class:?]
> at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(SourceFile:135) ~[Main.class:?]
> ... 6 more
> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
> at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.LaunchClassLoader.findClass(LaunchClassLoader.java:177) ~[**launchwrapper-of-2.2.jar**:2.2]
> at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418) ~[?:1.8.0_251]
> at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351) ~[?:1.8.0_251]
> at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_251]
> at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2583) ~[?:1.8.0_251]
> at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1916) ~[?:1.8.0_251]
> at net.optifine.reflect.FieldLocatorTypes.(FieldLocatorTypes.java:25) ~[FieldLocatorTypes.class:?]
> at net.optifine.reflect.Reflector.(Reflector.java:489) ~[Reflector.class:?]
> at l.i(CrashReport.java:101) ~[l.class:?]
> at l.(CrashReport.java:54) ~[l.class:?]
> at l.h(CrashReport.java:425) ~[l.class:?]
> at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(SourceFile:135) ~[Main.class:?]
> ... 6 more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the newer tutorial using the official launcher:

https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=78&t=284448

Comment: I followed the 64 bit case and it worked nicely! Thanks!